# Checking if same letter appears 3 times consecutively in string

Tags: c++

```
// a is some string;
b=a.length; 
for(int i=1; i<b; i++)
{
    if(a[i-1]==a[i]==a[i+1])
        {
            cout <<a[i]<<endl;
//more to add
        }
}
```

Want check if same 3 or more letters appears - what is wrong here?

Comment: `a[i-1]==a[i]==a[i+1]` should be `a[i-1]==a[i] && a[i]==a[i+1]`. But there is also the index out of range problem: `i < b` should be `i < b - 1`.

Comment: Thanks it works - but why my version is wrong? if(a==a==a) vs if (a==a and a==a)?

Comment: `a == b == c` doesn't do what you expect. First the left most comparison is made: `a == b`. This can be true or false. Then that result is compared to `c`. I.e. `false == c` or `true == c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific problem is that:

```
a[i-1]==a[i]==a[i+1]
```

evaluates as

```
(a[i-1] == a[i]) == a[i+1]
```

which is either

```
true == a[i+1]
false == a[i+1]
```

neither of which is probably what you want. Furthermore, when `i == a.size()`, `a[i+1]` would read off the end of the string, which is undefined behavior.

Also your title claims that you want to check if a letter occurs more than 2 times, but your code, even if fixed, would check that it occurs 3 times consecutively. If you really want to check for 3 occurrences, just use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    if (std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), a[i]) >= 3) {
        // success!
    }
}
```

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Nope, it's left-to-right. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b461ce695a6ff250).

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation (linear time complexity) of checking N consecutive char in the string,

```
const std::size_t N = 3;
std::string text { "this is a string" };
std::size_t index = 0;
std::size_t num_same_char = 1;

while (index + N - num_same_char < text.size()) {
  if (num_same_char == N) {
    // found at index
    break;
  }
  if (text[index] == text[index + num_same_char]) {
    num_same_char++;
  }
  else {
    num_same_char = 1;
    index += num_same_char;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// a is some string;
b=a.length; 
for(int i=1; i<b-1; i++) **//Iterate till b-1 not b**
{
    if(a[i-1]==a[i] && a[i]==a[i+1])
        {
            cout <<a[i]<<endl;
            //more to add
        }
}
```

Hope this helps.